# make menu active for categories redirected to cms page in magento

Tags: url-rewriting, navigation, magento-1.7

I have few categories in a *Magento* site that have been redirected to *cms pages* through URL rewrite. The problem is that since the category view page has been redirected to the *cms page* the navigation menu selected is not displayed as active. How can I display these menus as active?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i didn't find the exact way for the problem, but finally i found a quite easy workaround. Don't know if its the best practice, but this is what i did. i placed this code in header.phtml

```
<?php
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
?>
<?php if ($routeName == 'cms'): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if ($identifier == 'home'): ?>
        jQuery('li.nav-1').addClass('active');
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($identifier == 'gallery'): ?>
        jQuery('li.nav-2').addClass('active');
<?php endif ?>
<?php if ($identifier == 'blog'): ?>
        jQuery('li.nav-3').addClass('active');
<?php endif ?>
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

if there is any better way, please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Go to that particular category through catalog/manage categories and that select the category which you want to enable. next to that you can see an option as ENABLE with YES/NO options. Select YES and save the category. Delete the cache and reindex if you have any problems after editing also.

Comment: the categories are already active. what i actually want is the menu item in the navigation for those category to display as active, i.e. to have the class active. but since these categories have been redirected to _cms_ page, these menu items are not shown active.

Comment: Still I didnt understand what your menu item is?? or what do u mean by menu item??

Comment: i mean that the categories are added to navigation by selecting the include in navigation as "yes". but few of these categories are redirected to  _cms_ pages by _url_ rewriting. these category labels displayed in the navigation are not displayed as active when we are on the _cms_ page